# How to autosubmit price filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I'm trying to auto-submit the default search filter.

```
<div class="price_slider_amount" data-step="10">
    <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="70" data-min="70" placeholder="Preț Minim" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="1140" data-max="1140" placeholder="Preț Maxim" style="display: none;">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Filtrează</button>
</div>

<div class="price_label" style="">

    Price: <span class="from">500&nbsp;</span> 
    —
    <span class="to">1.140&nbsp;</span>

</div>
```

I tried like this

```
$(".price_label span").change(function() {
    $(".price_slider_amount").submit();
});
```

Comment: You can submit only forms. So, you should add the `<form>` tag to you inputs or you should use ajax request.

Comment: it is inside of a <form> tag, I just forgot to paste it

Comment: my main problem is how can use the js change function for the span values

Comment: Are u sure, that you wanna depend on `span` values? Why you are not using `inputs` to handle changes?

Comment: the CMS platform works this way, These are the values that are changing when I move the price filter up/down, so if I could get the value in the span or just know when the span is changing it would solve the problem

Comment: I would say, that might be much more efficient and correct to detect slider changes and submit the form using them. Add your slider example here and we will resolve this issue

Comment: it is ok if I paste it here like this ?

Comment: <div class="price_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style=""><div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 2.80374%; width: 97.1963%;"></div><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 2.80374%;"></span><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 100%;"></span></div>

Comment: Is it jQuery ui slider?

Comment: yes, I tried to target the style changes as well but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, it's very simple to handle slider's changes. Here you go:

```js
$('.price_slider').slider();

$( ".price_slider" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
 console.log('Your new value: ' + ui.value)
  
  //here you can submit your form or do whatever stuff you need
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="price_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="">
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 2.80374%; width: 97.1963%;"></div><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 2.80374%;"></span><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 100%;"></span></div>
```

For this and many other slider's features you should use [official doc](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/).

Comment: Glad to help you :)